# How to know when cron task was run last time?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I have the following task:

```
- description: Task is run every 2 hours
  url: /task
  schedule: every 2 hours synchronized
```

Is there any way to know in my python code when it was run last time (date and time)?
The idea I have now is to store that in memcache when it is finished to run. But is there any other better way?

PS. Another problem I have is with the case when memcache is empty. How can I calculate when last run was?

Comment: You can't, not without storing the information of the last run *somewhere*. Cron, by itself, does not track that for you.

Comment: You can't rely on memcache for this sort of thing where if it's gone you have no backup or if you care about losing the data in memcache.

Comment: @PaulC, surely - now I read from/write to datastore, if no memcache value is available.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, please post your reply as answer, so I will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, not without storing the information of the last run *somewhere*. Cron, by itself, does not track that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Why not add an extra bit of code to the file that is ran that creates a log, like a text file?

Comment: Such approach will consume GAE quotas.

Comment: Nonsense, don't tell that tracking the last cron run in a single file per cron job allocates significant resources.

Comment: One can not write to files on GAE.

Comment: Could it not easily write a log to a separate server?